# highcharts datatable - function parameters

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatable

I want to display a datatable below my highcharts graphs.
I found on the Highcharts FAQ a [running example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/).

```
Highcharts.drawTable = function() {...}
```

I need to display many datatables, so i want to refactor my code in order to be able to give display parameters to the Highcharts.drawTable function. (this avoid many code duplication !)

I try to add arguments to the Highcharts.drawtable function, and give value on the function call. But I got an error

> chart.xAxis isn't defined

[Live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9zXM/1033/)

Could you, please, help me in order to give parameters to the Highcharts.drawtable function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call drawTable function in load function, instead of reference.

```
load: function(){
            Highcharts.drawTable(this, 310, 100, 0, '', 20, 20, 2.5)
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z9zXM/1035/